# Access to WordPress page code not accessible or seen in admin dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

We have a website developed in Wordpress by a third party. We need to add a java script function and onClick event to an individual page of our website.

The page has a div with some divs that mimic a button. They are just text with anchor tags, inside divs. We are particularly interested in one particular one. (i.e. $2.00 Off Coupon) which when clicked downloads a PDF document. We would also like it to call a function.

[image: $2.00 Off Coupon]

In Chrome, when I look at the code for that element, it looks like this (see red circled area):

[image]

With in the WordPress admin dashboard, the code for those buttons is not available, as it was custom made by the third-party developer.

e.g.

[image]

My Question is, is this code in a template, theme, or page code stored in database? How can I modify this anchor tag to include an onClick event to call the function I need?

Any help to guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated as I am a WordPress Novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code located in Page Template file in your WordPress theme.
Try to find file with name page-home.php of something else.
This file should start from this code:

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: Home
 */
```

Or try a bad solution to the problem

```
$('.home-ctas').on('click', 'a[data-emalabel="$2.00 off coupon"]', function(){
    // your function
});
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I found a php file called "call-to-action" in the themes folder.  It has the anchor "<a class="download-cta track" href="<?php echo $visit_cta_asset['url']; ?>" target="_blank" data-emacategory="CTA" data-emalabel="Visitor Guide" onClick="callCouponDownload();">"   , I added the onClick event to the end as you can see. Where do I place the javaScript function "callCouponDownload" ?

Comment: you can add js function to the footer for testing. If everything will be ok - you can find some js file in this theme or you can create your own js file and include it to this theme using "wp_register_script" and "wp_enqueue_script"